# Changing cell image from another cell textclick

Tags: html

HI i have created table in HTML from one cell of that table i want to change another cell image or text how its possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What is the criteria to criteria to select another cell?

Answer (score 0):

in your head section you need to put little css code as
`<style type="text/css">
.turnitred {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
}
</style>`

and your td, the one you want to change the colour should have an id and that style you gave on above style text... on click change the bg of the td with according id for example:
`<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="94"><div class="turnitred" onclick ="changebg.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000'">Turn it red</div></td>
    <td width="90" id="changebg">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Comment: sorry...you can use: color: #000000; for the text in style instead of background-color:white;... and then changebg.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000'